# Why get first parameter from request is wrong?

Tags: java, jsp

I was from a JSP page request to another JSP page with some parameters,the code is:

```
url="/hotModuel/baseinfo/siteinfo/commonPlaceAndUnit/commonPlaceAndUnitStatistics.jsp?keyType=SecurityKeyOther&sid=e13048f7-d253-4d50-acec-2981a5536d48";
$.ajax({
        url : url,
        cache: false,
        success : function(result) {
            proccessLoginResult(result,function(){
                $("#loading").hide();
                $("#contentDiv").html(result);
                setOrgSelect();
                setCrumbs(srcObj);
            });
        }
    });
```

In the commonPlaceAndUnitStatistics.jsp file,i use the request to get parameter,code is:

```
<%
String keyType = request.getParameter("keyType");
String sid= request.getParameter("sid");
%>
```

got the keyType's value is

> SecurityKeyOthersid=e13048f7-d253-4d50-acec-2981a5536d48

the sid's value is

> e13048f7-d253-4d50-acec-2981a5536d48

but get parameter in the Filter:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest,
            ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
    String keyType= request.getParameter("keyType");
    String sid= request.getParameter("sid");
}
```

the tow parameter's value is right,Why is this?

Comment: Please format your question.

Comment: ... and add the code you are using.

Comment: Maybe `&amp;`? At least `&` isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this on Ajax request.
Change url to : `url="/hotModuel/baseinfo/siteinfo/commonPlaceAndUnit/commonPlaceAndUnitStatistics.jsp.`
And put parameter into body of ajax request like that:

```
$.ajax({
        url : url,
        data : { keyType: SecurityKeyOther, sid: e13048f7-d253-4d50-acec-2981a5536d48},
        cache: false,
        success : function(result) {
            proccessLoginResult(result,function(){
                $("#loading").hide();
                $("#contentDiv").html(result);
                setOrgSelect();
                setCrumbs(srcObj);
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Even i don't know why is this,but also thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

It is printing as expected , when i send the url as ,

```
<a href="two.jsp?keytype=something&sid=1234567&key2=value2">Click me!</a>
```

On printing,

```
<%= request.getParameter("keytype") %><br/>
<%= request.getParameter("sid") %> <br />
<%= request.getParameter("key2") %> <br/>
```

will output,

> something
>
> 1234567
>
> value2